# figuring this out whats the main problem and even i downloaded aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar but where to paste this file?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/Anand/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Anand/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Anand/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Anand/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
    file:/C:/Users/Anand/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Anand/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
Required by:
    project :slideMenuLibrary
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a google() repository in your build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      google() // <----
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
  }
} 
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google() // <----
      jcenter()
}
```

Comment: That's not a dependency, that's a repository. However, don't use alpha versions. Use the latest stable versions for the gradle: `3.2.1`